# Retrieve a UserId from OrgDefinedId using Valence

Tags: php, desire2learn, valence

I want to retrieve user's profile by inputting the user's `OrgDefinedId` (in order to get the `UserId`).

I know of 2 ways to get a user's profile:
`/d2l/api/lp/(version)/profile/(profileId)`
and
`/d2l/api/lp/(version)/profile/user/(userId)`

Is there something along the lines of:
`/d2l/api/lp/(version)/profile/(OrgDefinedID)`
or something to return just the `UserId` using the `OrgDefinedId`?

If anyone could help me with this, that would be awesome!

Thanks!
-- The Valence Newbie

Answer (score 0):

/d2l/api/lp/(version)/users/?orgDefinedId=idHere

returns the user by org defined id. Then you could use that to get the profile.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for!